# Segmentation fault in sqlcxt()

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I am using the below function in my C code for connecting to the oracle database. The below function is causing segmentation fault sometime while work at the other time

```
static int Connect(char *string)
{
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    static char login[80];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    strcpy((char *)login, string);

    EXEC SQL CONNECT :login ;

    if (sqlca.sqlcode < 0) 
        return(-1);
    return(0);
}
```

Below is the debugger report generated with the core file. Any suggestions on this.

```
program terminated by signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address)
0xffffffffffffffff:     <bad address 0xffffffffffffffff>
Current function is Connect
    375    sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn);

  [20] 0xffffffff7e587078(0x0, 0x100210f80, 0xffffffff7fffc850, 0x1000e4dd0, 0xff000000000000, 0x8080808080808080), at 0xffffffff7e587078
=>[21] login(orastring = 0xffffffff7fffcef8 "user123/abcd@sunn.adams"), line 375 in "connect.c"
```

Comment: many years since I did Pro*C but shouldn't the connect be - EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password USING :tns;

Comment: @Daven, I stated my database connection works sometime, so should'nt be an issue with the connect statement. It works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

From the debugger report, seg fault is because of accessing inaccessible memory.

I would suggest two places to put some checks. 
(a) Check input parameter `'string'` for `NULL` values before using it. 
(b) Use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`

Comment: Beware, `strncpy` does not guarantee NUL termination!

Comment: @bstpierre C-99 says that strncpy guarantees NULL termination. Please refer to section 7.19.6.5 on the standard available at this link: 

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf


Apologies for responding so late.

Comment: `strncpy` is described in 7.21.2.4, and there is a specific footnote (#263) that says: `Thus, if there is no null character in the first n characters of the array pointed to by s2, the result will not be null-terminated.` You referred to the description of `snprintf` (7.19.6.5), which *does* guarantee NUL termination.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I wonder what it means. The statements in 7.19.6.5 and 7.21.2.4 seem contradicting. Or am I missing something?

Comment: 7.19.6.5 has nothing to do with `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Have had many similar issues (using Oracle 8.1.7) and most of what I've found on the 'net simply says: Oracle Bug (especially if sqlcxt eventually calls lxchcsn

I had a program running 25 threads which seemed to work.  I changes some settings that meant an increase in the frequency of DB calls and this issue started to occur.  When I put mutexes around the DB calls, the issue went away (which is bizarre because I could see 25 individual DB connections - each thread had its own context) - and putting in the mutexes sort of defeats the purpose of multi-threading.

Basically, I think it's an Oracle issue